# How to make everything opaque in scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have recently updated from matplotlib 3.3.0 to 3.3.4. However, it seems some default behaviors have changed.

The particular problem I'm having right now is that scatter plots are not as opaque as they used to be. But I cannot pin down to a particular option here.
These are the variations of code I have run:

```
plt.scatter(y[:,0], y[:,1], color='r', s=0.01, marker='o')
plt.scatter(y[:,0], y[:,1], color='r', s=0.01, marker='.')
plt.scatter(y[:,0], y[:,1], c='r', s=0.01)
plt.scatter(y[:,0], y[:,1], c='r', s=0.01, alpha=1.0)
```

Everytime I get something like this which looks like a density map:

[image]

However, I want a scatter plots where each points have equal brightness in the scatter plot.

For comparison, here is the same code ran on matplotlib 3.3.4 (left) and 3.3.0 (right). You can see 3.3.0 is more opaque than that of 3.3.4.

[image]

The reason I needed to upgrade to 3.3.4 is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711437/matplotlib-3-3-0-not-working-in-firefox-93-or-chrome-95). Probably rolling back to 3.3.0 is an option. But I hope to avoid it.

Comment: Your figure at the end is really small and hard to see any difference, but can you specify `markerfacecolor`?

Comment: No. `markerfacecolor` doesn't work. It produces an error.

Comment: Hmm....I looked at the souce for matplotlib.pyplot.scatter in [3.3.4](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#scatter) and [3.3.0](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#scatter) and don't see any differences, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: Yeah. Probably it's some rendering issue. I'm not sure either.